# Как отсортировать словарь по ключам вложенного словаря?

Tags: python, сортировка, словари, python-3.7, анализ-данных

Как корректно отсортировать словарь по ключам вложенного словаря?

Например:

```
data = {
'key1':{'name':'John', 'job':'economist', 'date':'05.09.1967'}, 
'key2':{'name':'James', 'job':'ecologist', 'date':'15.04.1986'}, 
'key3':{'name':'Ivan', 'job':'owner', 'date':'23.11.1982'}, 
}
```

Как можно отсортировать такой словарь по значению `date`, чтобы на выходе получили порядок `key1,key3,key2`?

Пробовал `.sort` и `sorted` с `lambda` по `key`, но корректного результата не удалось достичь.

Comment: Словарь это неупорядоченная коллекция, сложно будет её отсортировать

Comment: @Dareten Но с 3.7 Python же сохраняет порядок вставки, как я понимаю

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственная "сложность" в данной задаче это то, что даты представлены как строки в формате `dd.mm.YYYY`, а при сравнении и сортировке строк используется [лексикографический порядок сортировки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

Т.е. это когда `"30.01.1900"` > `"01.01.2020"`, потому, что первый символ `"3"` > `"0"`. Эту "проблему" можно решить либо преобразовав строку с датой к объекту типа `datetime` (см. решение ниже) либо изменив формат даты на `YYYY.mm.dd` - тогда востаточно будет сделать: `res = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].get("date")))`

**решение на Vanilla Python:**

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

res = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: DT.strptime(x[1].get("date"), "%d.%m.%Y")))
```

---

результат:

```
In [35]: res
Out[35]:
{'key1': {'name': 'John', 'job': 'economist', 'date': '05.09.1967'},
 'key3': {'name': 'Ivan', 'job': 'owner', 'date': '23.11.1982'},
 'key2': {'name': 'James', 'job': 'ecologist', 'date': '15.04.1986'}}
```

Comment: спасибо! Да, проще хранить в datetime. Тогда достаточно res = dict(sorted(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].get("date"))), да.

Answer (score 1):

Решение с использованием [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd   # pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
res = (df
       .assign(d=pd.to_datetime(df["date"]))
       .sort_values("d")
       .drop(columns="d")
       .to_dict("index"))
```

---

результат:

```
In [17]: res
Out[17]:
{'key1': {'name': 'John', 'job': 'economist', 'date': '05.09.1967'},
 'key3': {'name': 'Ivan', 'job': 'owner', 'date': '23.11.1982'},
 'key2': {'name': 'James', 'job': 'ecologist', 'date': '15.04.1986'}}
```